# Deploying Qt application on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: qt, osx-snow-leopard

I am developing a C++ application on Mac OS X 10.8 with Xcode/Qt 4.8.4. I would like it to run on Mac OS X 10.6 and higher. In order to do that I set Xcode deployment target to 10.6, also I use macdeployqt. It works fine on Mac OS X 10.8, but on 10.6 there are lots and lots of issues.

The application crashes because of missing frameworks which are located in different places on 10.6 and 10.8:

> Dyld Error Message:  Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText 
>   Referenced from:
>   /Volumes/deploy/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
>
> Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO 
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
>
> ...Similar QtWebKit, QtNetwork issues  etc etc...

And there are trickier issues are about missing symbols in some system libraries, like libobjc.A.dylib, libSystem.B.dylib, libc++abi.dylib, libc++.1.dylib etc:

> Dyld Error Message:  Symbol not found:
>   __dispatch_queue_attr_concurrent  Referenced from: /tmp/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libobjc.A.dylib  Expected
>   in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib  in
>   /tmp/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libobjc.A.dylib

Could somebody explain how to fix this? Is it possible at all to target Mac OS X 10.6 when using Qt 4.8.4? Perhaps, Qt 4.8.4 is not fully compatible with 10.6? I have tried to set QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.6 in the .pro file, I am using macdeployqt just passing MyApp.app as the only argument. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, you are far better off just installing 10.6 on a partition and doing you builds there. I've been building on Mac OS 10.6 against Qt 4.8.4 and using macdeployqt, my application happily works on 10.5 through to 10.8 with no problems